# How to remove the 'None'?

Tags: python, arrays, list, return-value

**this was the task**

> A left rotation operation on an array of *size* shifts each of the array's elements 1 unit to the left. For example, if 2 left rotations are performed on array [1,2,3,4,5], then the array would become [3,4,5,1,2].

I tried solving this problem by storing each item in a variable `x` whenever I wanted to rotate it to the left side ,then I would removed this item , next I will append this item once again in the array and I had all of this a for loop.It really solved the problem. However, the output wasn't exactly as expected because of the `None` appearing in the second line plus a third blank line.

what is that `None`? why did it appear? and how to get rid of it?

This is my code:

```
def rotate(d, a):
    for _ in range(d):
        x = a[0]
        a.remove(a[0])
        a.append(x)

    print(*a)
```

this was the result:

[image: result]

Comment: Your function returns `None`, since you never return anything.  Try `return ' '.join(a)` and then print that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. This code never calls the function, so you need to make a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. I would guess that you're supposed to return `a`, not print it.

Comment: Looks like you are also trying to print the return from `rotate` which you aren't showing.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include enough information to answer in the question, but it seems clear you are invoking your code from within a framework (e.g. hackerrank) that expects you to `return` a value instead of `print`ing it.

The `None` comes from the default return of python, i.e. your function `rotate` does not return anything, so the surrounding code:

```
answer = rotate(foo, bar)
print(answer)
```

gives you the additional `None`.